# How to show a custom TTPhotoView when clicking on a thumb from TTThumbsViewController

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm creating an image viewer app similar to the facebook app using Three20. When the user clicks on a thumbnail, I would like to show a completely different full image view. Instead of just the image and a caption, I would like to show the image in only a portion of the screen along with some other information from my model. How do I do this?

I've already created a custom `TTPhotoViewController` and am using it to return a custom `TTPhotoView` class for the full image views. I don't know how to subclass `TTPhotoView` such that it can display other information. Because it descends from `TTImageView`, it appears that it's only able to display the image full screen. There's lots of code in `TTImageView` having to do with layers and other Objective-C concepts that I'm not familiar with. Do I need to do something with that? I don't think it's as easy as loading up a NIB and displaying that, but I love it if it was.

Answer (score 1):

In you subclass of TTThumbsPhotoViewer just override this method

```
- (TTPhotoViewController*)createPhotoViewController {
  return [[[MyTTPhotoViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

The solution above works also but this is how is intended to do this. Because in didSelectPhoto method there is more logic what should be done and at the end of this method "createPhoto...." is called for pushing :)

Answer (score 0):

In your inherited class of TTThumbsViewController override this method

```
- (void)thumbsTableViewCell:(TTThumbsTableViewCell*)cell didSelectPhoto:(id<TTPhoto>)photo 
{
    YourImageViewControler *controller =  [[[YourImageViewControler alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];

    //Set photo
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```